# Set UIDatePicker text color for dates outside of date range swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I am playing with a `UIDatePicker` in my project and I have decided to change the text color to white with

```
self.datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
```

I also have a minimum date set to today's date. The issue I am having is that the date and time text outside of my minimum date is still grey making it hard to see on my screen. I have been browsing the documentation and am not able to find a list of what key value pairs are available to the class in order to fix this. Thanks.

[image: Image of datepicker]

Comment: The code in your question should be avoided. It's undocumented and could break or cause a crash in a future update to iOS. `UIDatePicker` does not support any customization. Create or find your own custom date picker widget if you want such a feature.